# Pandas column sum base on row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame:

```
      year  month  day  highest_temp
0      1961      1    1           7.9
1      1961      1    2           9.2
2      1961      1    3           7.3
3      1961      1    4          11.5
4      1961      1    5           7.7
5      1961      1    6           8.6
6      1961      1    7           9.1
7      1961      1    8          11.8
8      1961      1    9           6.9
```

I want to sum the highest_temp column from 1st of Feb until this sum >= 600 for all years of this data frame. I tried iterrows(), sum() but I didn't get the result I want. Thank for helping

EDIT: 
Base on @bubble answer, I got the following result:

```
57   1961      2   27          11.6     273.2
58   1961      2   28          11.7     284.9
59   1961      3    1          15.3     300.2
60   1961      3    2          18.9     319.1
..    ...    ...  ...           ...       ...
81   1961      3   23          15.5     584.3
82   1961      3   24          13.0     597.3
```

However I still want the value surpasses the threshold which is 600. For example: in the above result I want the final values plus one more row.
Here is my code base on @bubble:

```
value = 600            
df2=df2.drop(df2[df2.month<2].index)

cumsums = df2.groupby(['year']).transform('cumsum')['highest_temp']


df2.loc[cumsums < value, 'cumsum_t'] = cumsums[cumsums < value]

result = df2.loc[cumsums < value, :]
```

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: Look into [cumsum](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
df.loc[df.highest_temp.cumsum()<600,:]
```

This selects sub-dataframe by condition " sum of hightest_temp less 600". You can apply cumsum again, e.g.

```
data = df.loc[df.highest_temp.cumsum()<600, :]
data.loc[:, 'cumsum_t'] = data.highest_temp.cumsum()
```

Also, you can use `groupby` method to reset cumsum for each month:

```
value = 600                                                                       
cumsums = df.groupby(['month']).transform('cumsum')['highest_temp']                 
df.loc[cumsums < value, 'cumsum_t'] = cumsums[cumsums < value]                        
result = df.loc[cumsums < value, :]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, its really helpful. However I need to begin the sum from the month column = 2 until this sum surpasses 600 and I want to this for all the year in the data frame. Do you have any suggestion?